# Series: a real life example?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I can't imagine a real life situation where one can apply the numeric series concept. My goal is to find a motivation for the study of this matter.

I thought of applying a series to a certain sequence. But the sequences that I thought of were those that give how much something measures at a given time. I think that it's not proper to apply a series in this kind of example. The goal is not to sum the measures, but to sum the growths beteween each times.

Can you give me a real life example, where one can apply a numeric series?
Thanks

Comment: approximations of $\pi$, calculations of logarithms, exponentials, etc...

Comment: Would nummerically solving differential equations by Euler's method or RK qualify?

Comment: @Rustyn -- Calculating $\pi$ or logarithms or exponentials is not done by using series in "real life". You just use computer library functions to calculate these things, and these functions typically do not make use of series.

Comment: @João -- I edited to correct grammar. Please make sure I didn't change the meaning.

Comment: @bubba thanks. I'm neither a english native, nor a proficient speaker.

Comment: @bubba How do you think the "computer library function" computes $e^x$ or $\sin x$, if not by using their series representations?

Comment: @fgp -- it's somewhat secret, but, in the 1960s, when this was a hot topic, the main method was to use domain reduction and then approximation by a Chebyshev polynomial or a rational function. Minimax approximations, anyway. Series expansions are no good because they focus on only a single point. You want an approximation that's uniformly good throughout some interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much of the mathematics used every day for e.g. engineering is ultimately based on infinite series. The series themselves aren't used explicitly most of the time, but the computation methods are derived from them. Often the simplest way to express a result is as a series, to get the numerical value you need to compute it's value. The best way known to compute various quantities of practical interest are series.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example for the following series :

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i}$$

A snail fell in a $1m$ well and wants to go back up. Every day it goes back up half the distance left to go up.

When will he reach the top? 
 I had that question when I was still in primary school and the answer is never.

Perhaps you could ask another question such as : After 100 days, how much does he have left to climb?

Of course this is just an idea, not exactly a real life situation, but you can change values and context quite easily from here to make new examples.

You could also have a situation where somebody shares a large amount of money and every time the next person has a fraction of what the previous one had and so on creating a series this way.

Comment: The parraph before the last one really calmed me down: I was beginning to believe that someone *really* saw a snail who fell into a well and which really began to crawl up the walls but, because of the well known magical reasons that exist during night, he fell down *exactly* half the way he crawled up during the day...phew!

Comment: @DonAntonio. Thanks for the humor you bring here ! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

when you loan money in a bank, say at 4.5% year. 
the way they compute how much you hown if the loan is 25 years is pretty much a good approximation of an infinte serie.

The way you calculate how much concrete you need for building a bridge uses series.

Any numerical approximation of the "real things" use series.

And so on...

Comment: Most numerical approximations don't use series.

Comment: that's true. I should have written "many" and not "any"...

Comment: @vonbrand -- not good ones, anyway.

Comment: @user126154 -- how do you use a series to calculate how much concrete is needed for a bridge?? You mean to do the stress calculations?

Answer (score 0):

The fibonacci sequence is based on an infinite power series. I find those the most interesting because they can be used to model a ton of stuff found in nature. And a lot of inventions were inspired by looking at nature.